# GWT MouseOutHandler not fired, when moving to fast over icon

Tags: gwt, tooltip, mouseevent, onmouseout

I have a Tooltip class, which adds tooltip functionality to an element.

When I move too fast over an element, the MouseOutHandler sometimes does not fire and so the tooltip stays visible.

Here is how I add the handlers:

```
((HasMouseOverHandlers) source).addMouseOverHandler(this);
((HasMouseOutHandlers) source).addMouseOutHandler(this);
((HasMouseMoveHandlers) source).addMouseMoveHandler(this);
```

Did I forget something, or is it normal for onmouseout events not to fire, if I move the mouse too fast?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626429/onmouseout-event-not-triggered-when-moving-mouse-fast-gwt-all-browsers

HTH